# Regex to extract categories from URL

Tags: php, regex

I have a Slug `aktuell/blog/cat1/cat2/cat3` and need a Regex to extract all category-segments (all segements after `'aktuell/blog'`) from this Slug. 
The count of cataegory-segements may vary from zero to infinity.

I have already tried several ways but it never works as expected... 
My last attempt was:

```
^aktuell\\/blog(?:\\/(\w+))*$/g
```

But this Regex returns just the last segment as match... 
What can i do to get all categories?

Thank's

Comment: Are you passing the segments into PHP as `$_GET` variables or is the URL only available as a string? If you're passing as variables, cycle through `$_GET` to retrieve the values. If not, then explode the string you have with the delimiter "/" and find the segments you want!

Comment: The URL is only available as string.

I have a routing class which deals with the regex patterns (from db) and returns me the route id and all matches. So I can not use explode... :(

Comment: Why not use this pattern: `aktuell\/blog\/(.*)` and explode on `"/"`?

Comment: Pure regex: `/(?:^aktuell\/blog|\G(?!^))(?:\/(\w+))/g`

Comment: @SebastianProske: I think **you** should post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the reminder, but I don't think it's worth the effort to write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/(?:^aktuell\/blog|\G(?!^))(?:\/(\w+))/`in combination with `preg_match_all()` works fine!

big thanks to @WiktorStribiżew and @SebastianProske

Comment: Since Sebastian does not want to provide an answer, I came up with my own suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This Regex works, but the php Regex-Engine can't handle matches in a repeating group. Every new match overrides the previous one...

So i have to repeat the group manually:

```
^aktuell\/blog(?:\/(\w+))?(?:\/(\w+))?(?:\/(\w+))?(?:\/(\w+))?(?:\/(\w+))?
```

Comment: Don't you really have access to multiple matches? See Sebastian's suggestion above that would work with `preg_match_all` function (if you remove `g` at the end).

Comment: Please let him know if his suggestion works, so that he could post an answer to get credit for his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to solve your problem:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri_arr = explode("/",$uri);
$cat = array();
array_map(function($v) use (&$cat){
    preg_match('/^cat\d$/',$v,$matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0){
        $cat[] = $matches[0];
      }
},$uri_arr);
print_r($cat);
```

Here is an [example](https://3v4l.org/QS09q)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that repeated captured groups always store the last captured value in their buffer.

You can use a `preg_match_all` with the following regex:

```
/(?:^aktuell\/blog|(?!^)\G)\/\K\w+/
```

or (to avoid escaping the forward slash):

```
'~(?:^aktuell/blog|(?!^)\G)/\K\w+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV9wI5/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^aktuell\/blog|(?!^)\G)` - Matches the start of string and `aktuell/blog` after it (see `^aktuell\/blog`), or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match in the string (with `(?!^)\G`)
- `\/` - matches a `/` symbol
- `\K` - makes the regex engine omit the text matched so far
- `\w+` - matches `/`, and then captures 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters.

Comment: Note that accepting answer posted by another user (I guess the first time) you will get 2 additional points.